# Saving an Image button's isSelected() property in onSaveInstanceState and restore it

Tags: java, android

Lets say I have an image button, which change image `onClick()` thus `isSelected()` property is true. How can I save this property in `onSaveInstanceState()` so that I can later restore it while rotating the phone?

Comment: Maybe save the state of the button somewhere else in an object which is persistent between orientation changes and check its value at `onCreate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, save the `isSelected()` property in `onSaveInstanceState()`

```
public final String STATE_SELECTED = "state_selected";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean(STATE_SELECTED, button.isSelected());
}
```

Then access and use this value in `onRestoreInstanceState()`

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    boolean selected = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_SELECTED);
    button.setSelected(selected);
    if (selected) // Do some stuff
    else //Do some other stuff
}
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** In response to your comment, here's how you do this for an array of buttons:

```
public final String STATE_SELECTED = "state_selected";
public Button[] buttons; // This is populated elsewhere

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    boolean[] selected = new boolean[buttons.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) selected[i] = buttons[i].isSelected();
    savedInstanceState.putBooleanArray(STATE_SELECTED, selected);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    boolean[] selected = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray(STATE_SELECTED);
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) button[i].setSelected(selected[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you veryyyyy much Eoin. The solution works perfect. And now time to move on to next stage, could you please suggest me how can i save these properties for an array of button? I am kind of new to these stuffs and might sound dumb, but i would highly appreciate any help you can do at this point. I have tried by making six private final attributes and was tried to store it to button[i], but i am failing (obviously)...

Comment: I've edited the question to show you how to do this - you can just create a `boolean` array and store that in `savedInstanceState`. For a list of data types that you can store in a `Bundle`, check out the [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) page in the docs